# Systemd - Pair RestartSec with StartLimitIntervalSec. Any issues with such config?

Tags: systemd, python

I created a systemd service file for Debian 11. It is for a python3 script that should always be running.

```
[Unit]
Description=Printer service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=user1
WorkingDirectory=/home/user1/myproject
ExecStart=/home/user1/myproject/venv/bin/python3 /home/user1/myproject/myscript.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am not sure how long it will take for the script to restart. Do I need to increase the `RestartSec` value? I guess I don't understand this directive. Let's say the script needs 5 seconds to fully activate, would have `RestartSec=1` disrupt that?

I also added `StartLimitIntervalSec=0` because I don't any rate limiting where systemd stops activating the service after certain number of failures. If the service fails for any reasons, would systemd attempt to keep restarting forever? What is the behavior if I don't specify `User`?

Lastly, are there any incompatibilities between the directives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`man systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RestartSec=) says:

> RestartSec=
>
> Configures the time to sleep before restarting a service (as
> configured with Restart=). Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or a
> time span value such as "5min 20s". Defaults to 100ms.

This is the amount of time where the service is stopped or failed.  It's okay if your script takes some time to start because it's in the "activating" stage there.

```
                     |----RestartSec------|
---------|-----------|--------------------|------------|----------
 running    stopping    stopped             starting     running
```

[`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StartLimitIntervalSec=interval) says:

> StartLimitIntervalSec=interval, StartLimitBurst=burst
>
> Configure unit start rate limiting. Units which are started more than *burst* times within an *interval* time span are not permitted to start any more. Use StartLimitIntervalSec= to configure the checking interval and StartLimitBurst= to configure how many starts per interval are allowed.
>
> *interval* is a time span with the default unit of seconds, but other units may be specified, see systemd.time(5). Defaults to DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec= in manager configuration file, and **may be set to 0 to disable any kind of rate limiting**. *burst* is a number and defaults to DefaultStartLimitBurst= in manager configuration file.

---

So if you have this, there is no conflict:

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=1s
StartLimitIntervalSec=3s
StartLimitBurst=2
```

What it will do is:

- When the unit stops/fails, wait 1s, then start it again
- If the unit fails to start 2 times in 3 seconds, then stop trying to restart the unit.

---

If you only have this:

```
Restart=always
```

then defaults are used which implies:

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=100ms
StartLimitIntervalSec=10s
StartLimitBurst=5
```

Then your behaviour will be:

- If the unit stops, wait 100ms, then start it again.
- If the unit fails to start 5 times within 10s, then stop trying to restart the unit.

---

Per your comment, "you can disable any kind of rate limiting".

```
Restart=always
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
```

Then your behaviour will be:

- If the unit stops, wait 100ms, then start it again.
- No rate limiting

Comment: "If the unit fails to start 2 times in 3 seconds, then stop trying to restart the unit." `Restart=always` can be coupled with `StartLimitIntervalSec=0` to override the defaults right? In that case would the service if failed would to attempted to restart forever?

Comment: Correct, I edited the answer to **bold** that part of the reference.  In that case, the service will restart whenever it stops or fails, and it will never reach any rate limiting